# How can I delete n number of multiple rows in Excel at one time?

Tags: excel

I have more than 50,000 rows in my excel , and only first 1000 are useful, and rest aren't. How can i delete the rest 49000 rows in a way , which saves my time.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first row and then with holding shift the last row all rows inbetween are selected. After that you can delete with rightclick delete rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the cell A1001, and then hold `CTRL` + `shift` + `PgDn` (arrow that points down) to select all the 49,000 cells. Then press `shift` + `ENTER` to select the entire rows of those 49,000 cells. Finally, click `right click` and select `Delete entire row`.